# How to write Apple push notification using Spring AMQP?

Tags: spring, apple-push-notifications, spring-amqp

I am new to push notification. I would like to write a code using Spring AMQP which will send notification message to APN. I have .p12, certification and .pem files with me. Can anybody help me in writing the code using Spring AMQP which will send notification message.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What have you tried on coding ? APNS is just establishing a SSH channel to Apple's Push Server & write data to the channel.

Comment: I created a Spring AMQP module which will be calling RabbitMQ to save the JSON which is coming as a part of request and this json object I would like to pass it to APN. Following is the sample code which I tried using javaapns

Comment: public static void main(String[] args) {

    try {
      Push.alert("Hello World!", "p12file.p12", "passwordkeystore", false, "key");
    } catch (CommunicationException e) {
      // TODO Auto-generated catch block
      e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (KeystoreException e) {
      // TODO Auto-generated catch block
      e.printStackTrace();
    }

  }

Answer (score 0):

Spring AMQP is for sending messages to an AMQP broker, which in the case of spring is only RabbitMQ at this time. If you just have to use spring-amqp then you will need to create a producer using AmqpTemplate.convertAndSend. Then you will need a consumer that pulls messages off of the queue. See SimpleMessageListenerContainer and MessageListener for the consumer. Your consumer would contain the Push.alert("Hello World") code. Of course, the "Hello World" string would be replaced with whatever payload you are pushing to APNS.